# Possible to run Kibana without it creating an index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to make it possible for developers to spin up a local instance of Kibana against our Elastic instance running in Kubernetes, maybe using kubectl port-forward or similar, mostly for troubleshooting purposes. I know it is possible to do, renaming the .kibana index, but it is easy to shoot oneself in the foot this way IMHO, and I would prefer to run Kibana as a read only user. Even if I in the future need to modify data, I don't want Kibana to touch any of the indices ever, (without a developer running an explicit query to do so if we decide to allow that).

My very naïve approach was to just grant read only access to Kibana, but then it crashes, saying it can't create the .kibana index.

Is it in any way possible to run Kibana (maybe with reduced functionality) without ever needing to store state in Elastic? Or should I simply give up and look for another tool to disect the data?

Background: We had issues with the .kibana index (and its renames) becoming unassigned since we basically run against ephemeral (or ramdisk) storage. When new versions are deployed, data is sometimes lost (this is by design). Our application will deal with its own indices but the .kibana index causes the cluster state to become yellow. While there are of course ways around this, I want to play it safe and forbid Kibana from every modifying anything, if possible. Otherwise I would probably look for a safer tool to use for troubleshooting (we basically need the Dev tools).

Comment: what version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Did you check it? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/space-rbac-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you. I am using Elastic 7.6.2 and I think the links refer to setting up access to users of Kibana. I want to make sure the Kibana service itself never writes to Elasticsearch, not even on a system level. I am fine with losing state on restart.

Comment: Kibana needs to be able to write data to an index, but you can have multiple instances with different kibana index, just need to point to a different index in each local `kibana.yml`, for example use the username as the kibana index for the user. `kibana.index: .username1`

Comment: Thanks. Yes that is what I said in the question, but I prefer not to do that. If you can find a canonical source of what you just said, write it up as an answer.